Android Glance Widget Text with marquee
I have simple glance widget, that have text inside.
provideContent{
    Text(
        text = "Some really long text",
        style = TextStyle(
              color = ColorProvider(Color.White),
              fontSize = 18.sp,
              textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        ),
        maxLines = 1,
        modifier = GlanceModifier.padding(start = 5.dp, end = 5.dp)
    )
}

However, when the text is really long, it goes either on new line, or can be limited on one line (that is the maxLines attribute). Since the Glance is relatively new, it seems there is no marquee support for Text. At least I did not find it anywhere. Can somebody help and advise, how to make such behaviour, maybe advise some workaround? I believe this is rather needed functionality, since the widget has limited size and our text to display can be really long. Thank you.

Yeah, I can't find any explicit marquee support anywhere in the source either. You should be able to use an AndroidRemoteViews() to wrap a regular RemoteViews instance, and just set up your <TextView> with marquee in layout XML. The dev page on that is here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/glance/interoperability. That's all Glance would end up doing internally anyway, if it had the option, but it's not really possible to provide every possible configuration, 'cause the internals are really just piecing together individual, pre-defined layouts.
